# Selecting a Record With a Max Value When Grouping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have a model called 'Project' with fields 'unique_id' and 'version' (as well as other irrelevant fields like name). The unique_id is unique to each project and each project has multiple versions ie.

unique_id | version 
        1              |      1 
        1               |     2 
        2               |     1

What I am trying to do is select the newest version of each project and add them to `@projects` for use by my view (where each project is displayed).

I have no idea how to do this but my thought process was to use `Projects.group(:unique_id).count` to get a hash of *unique_id* and count (aka the version) and use that information to pull each record via a  loop. That seems clumsy to me. I also know there is a maximum function but that that won't pull the record, only the max value. Help?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Group by the `unique_id` and select the records with `MAX` version:

```
Project.select('MAX(version), unique_id, id, name').group(:unique_id).all
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Is there any way to select the records without having to list each column that I want to pull? Along with name there are about 8 others columns. Or is the best way just to list them all in the () after 'name'?

Comment: I think you can use the SQL wildcard here: `select('MAX(version), *')`. Try that out.

Comment: Just an FYI for everyone. It turns out, while this code works great for SQLite, it breaks if the database is switched to postgreSQL (like when deploying the app on heroku)

Comment: And the reason is that when you group in postgresql you have to include the id column.

Comment: And the error from Postresql is PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "projects.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 9):

This should do what you require:

```
Projects.group(:unique_id).having('Max(version) >= version')
```

Comment: I prefer this as its a bit more rails-ish.

Comment: This is also the more appropriate answer, as `having` is intended to specify conditions for grouped fields. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#having https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.5/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-having